# Is it possible do make a GSM call without backgrounding the app?

Tags: android, android-intent, mobile, android-asynctask, gsm

I'm a newbie in Android. I have a task to make a call from the app without the app backgrounding or the app to be relaunched after a GSM call is made.

Here is my code:

```
 class DialInAndOpenApp extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ProgressDialog> {
    ProgressDialog mProrgessDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProrgessDialog.setMessage("loading");
        mProrgessDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProrgessDialog.show();

        //make the GSM call
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + 123));
        startActivity(callIntent);
        Log.e("Async", "we made the call");

    }

    @Override
    protected ProgressDialog doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startActivity(i);
        Log.e("Async", "backgrounded");

        return mProrgessDialog;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ProgressDialog result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        //open the app
        Intent openAppIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),      SplashScreen.class);
        startActivity(openAppIntent);
        mProrgessDialog.dismiss();
        Log.e("Async", "opened the app");

    }
}
```

and I call this in a OnClick method. It does the job on Lollipop, but on non Lollipop devices it doesn't bring the app to front. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.